# SQL Query with Case Statement with latest load time

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a *very* large set of data from which I need to select specific tags for every available time_stamp but if multiple time_stamps for a given tag exists, I need to select the one with the latest loadtimestamp.

This is a simplified version of my data set:

```
|tag_name   | value   |     time_stamp    |   loadtimestamp   |
|:---------:|:-------:|:-----------------:|:-----------------:|
|   TAG1    |   10    |2017-01-19 22:16:04|2017-01-19 22:49:58|
|   TAG2    |   89    |2017-01-19 22:16:04|2017-01-19 22:49:58|
|   TAG3    |   22    |2017-01-19 22:16:04|2017-01-19 22:49:58|
|   TAG1    |   12    |2017-01-19 22:17:05|2017-01-19 22:49:58|
|   TAG2    |   93    |2017-01-19 22:17:05|2017-01-19 22:49:58|
|   TAG3    |   15    |2017-01-19 22:17:05|2017-01-19 22:49:58|
|   TAG1    |   9     |2017-01-19 22:16:04|2017-01-22 12:29:12|
|   TAG2    |   88    |2017-01-19 22:16:04|2017-01-22 12:29:12|
|   TAG3    |   21    |2017-01-19 22:16:04|2017-01-22 12:29:12|
|   TAG1    |   15    |2017-01-19 22:18:05|2017-01-19 22:49:58|
|   TAG2    |   98    |2017-01-19 22:18:05|2017-01-19 22:49:58|
|   TAG3    |   23    |2017-01-19 22:18:05|2017-01-19 22:49:58|
```

Initially, I wasn't thinking about the loadtimestamp issue and my query was as follows:

```
select time_stamp, 
MAX(Case when tag_name = 'TAG1' then value else NULL END) as "Tagname 1",
MAX(Case when tag_name = 'TAG2' then value else NULL END) as "Tagname 2",
MAX(Case when tag_name = 'TAG3' then value else NULL END) as "Tagname 3",
from "DATATABLE".calculated_data
group by time_stamp
```

I use the case statement as I needed a way to give specific names to each tag in the data set.

The result was that at 22:16:04, I have multiple results/values for the tags.  My need is that I only have a single value for each tag/time_stamp and it is the one with the latest loadtimestamp.

I have seen several versions of queries trying to pull the latest date but I couldn't find a way to apply it while also using the case statement.

I tried a few versions with subqueries but I believe the result was that **each** time a tag was found, it queried the entire data set looking for the same tag and time_stamp and then selected the one with the latest loadtimestamp.   As my data set is ~50 million rows and my resulting table should be ~1 million, this approach was not feasible (and to be honest I never got it to really work).  My end approach needs to be somewhat optimized so that it can execute in a *reasonable* amount of time.

To be clear I am very new to SQL and a bit out of my depth so I apologize if this is overly basic or perhaps not clear.  I would greatly appreciate any help or direction on this problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 select t.tag_name ,t.time_stamp from 
 (select tag_name ,time_stamp ,
 row_number()over(partition by tag_name,time_stamp order by loadtimestamp 
 desc) as RN 
 from calculated_data)t
 where t.RN=1
```

Comment: So much appreciation to you Kapil!

Answer (score 0):

Kapil's answer worked great.  Full query only took ~3 minutes.

With the case statement, it looked like this in the end:

```
select t.time_stamp,
MAX(Case when tag_name = 'TAG1' then value else NULL END) as "Tagname 1",
MAX(Case when tag_name = 'TAG2' then value else NULL END) as "Tagname 2",
MAX(Case when tag_name = 'TAG3' then value else NULL END) as "Tagname 3",
 from 
 (select time_stamp, tag_name value,
 row_number()over(partition by tag_name , time_stamp, value order by loadtimestamp 
 desc) as RN 
 from calculated_data) t 
where t.RN = 1
group by t.time_stamp
order by t.time_stamp;
```